# Gnome streamer framegrabber mixing

Tags: linux, gstreamer

I have 4 usb framegrabbers in linux from which I would like to capture video and display it in 4 screens (which are mixed in one windows).

Running command gives what is supported by framegrabber:

```
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug=v4l2src:5 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! fakesink 2>&1 | sed -une '/caps of src/ s/[:;] /\n/gp'
```

Result:

```
0:00:00.015135255  4333      0x1e01630 DEBUG                v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:300:gst_v4l2src_negotiate:<v4l2src0> caps of src
video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)interleaved, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)bt601
video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)interleaved, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)bt601
video/x-raw, format=(string)YV12, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)interleaved, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)bt601
video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)interleaved, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)1:1:5:4
video/x-raw, format=(string)RGB, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)interleaved, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)1:1:5:4
```

When I am running:

```
#!/bin/bash
gst-launch-1.0 -e videomixer name=mix ! videoconvert ! autovideosink \
        videotestsrc pattern=13 ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2, framerate=30000/1001, width=720, height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-480 left=-720 ! mix. \
        videotestsrc pattern=1 ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2, framerate=30000/1001, width=720, height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-480 left=0 ! mix. \
        videotestsrc pattern=15 ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2, framerate=30000/1001, width=720, height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=-720 ! mix. \
        videotestsrc pattern=0 ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2, framerate=30000/1001, width=720, height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=0 ! mix.
```

It works.Four test windows shows up.

Now I would like to show /dev/video0 but it doesn't work.

```
Reports "Internal data flow error":
#!/bin/bash
gst-launch-1.0 -e videomixer name=mix ! videoconvert ! autovideosink \
        v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2, framerate=30000/1001, width=720, height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-480 left=-720 ! mix. \
        v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2, framerate=30000/1001, width=720, height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-480 left=0 ! mix. \
        v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2, framerate=30000/1001, width=720, height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=-720 ! mix. \
        v4l2src device=/dev/video3 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2, framerate=30000/1001, width=720, height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=0 ! mix.
```

Running it gives error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2948): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
EOS on shutdown enabled -- waiting for EOS after Error
Waiting for EOS...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstXvImageSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-xvimage: Output window was closed
Additional debug info:
xvimagesink.c(555): gst_xv_image_sink_handle_xevents (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstXvImageSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-xvimage
```

Could someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough points to put this as a comment.

I'm having exactly the same problem except my video source is an MJPEG stream.

I've managed to reach the point where the window is created by adding videoscale to the pipeline.

This would be the equivalent for you:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e videomixer name=mix ! videoconvert ! autovideosink \
        v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoscale ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2, framerate=30000/1001, width=720, height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-480 left=-720 ! mix. \
        v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videoscale ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2, framerate=30000/1001, width=720, height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-480 left=0 ! mix. \
        v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! videoscale ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2, framerate=30000/1001, width=720, height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=-720 ! mix. \
        v4l2src device=/dev/video3 ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2, framerate=30000/1001, width=720, height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=0 ! mix.
```

Unfortunately all I get is an empty window but at least it is progress.